# Is it possible to map an array contained in useState and then update the state with the setter function - react checklist

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, state, use-state

I am trying to create a check list component in-which I can toggle the checklist items to true/false and then display this data in a separate element.

When I try my example code it throws this error: TypeError: checkList.map is not a function

I've also looked at other hooks but I don't see an obvious solution.

Example Code:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const CheckListTest = () => {
    const [checklist, setChecklist] = useState([
        {name: 'option1', value: false},
        {name: 'option2', value: false},
    ]);
    return (
        <>
            {checklist.map((item) => {
                return item.value === true ? item.name : '';
            })}
            {checklist.map((item) => {
                return (
                    <div
                        onClick={() => {
                            setChecklist(...checklist, (item.value = !item.value));
                        }}
                    >
                        {item.name}
                    </div>
                );
            })}
        </>
    );
};
```

Example of UI:
[image: 2] - When clicking item from bottom list it should remove itself from the array and push to the list above. (Haven't gotten this far as I am still stuck)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please include your code in your question instead of linking to it off-site or posting images of it.  See [mre].

Comment: Looking the picture you're setting a new state and that is not an array so that is why map is not a valid method.

Comment: Jean, this worked. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the `setCheckList` function with the wrong numner of parameters. The setter in `useState` accepts one argument. Try changing the `setCheckList` function inside your `onClick` handler to this:

```js
setCheckList(checkList => {
  const newCheckList = [...checkList];
  // Do someting here to change the `newCheckList` variable, e.g.:
  if (!item.value) {
    const index = newCheckList.findIndex(item => item.value);
    newCheckList.splice(index, 1);
  }
  return newCheckList;
})
```